# How to make form validation in InertiaJS with Formhelper

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, inertiajs

Setup: Laravel 8 + Inertia JS with Vue 3

I'm trying to implement inline form.errors with InertiaJS like desribed here: https://inertiajs.com/forms#form-helper

But that doesn't work. All `form-helpers` like form.processing are available but not form.errors.

Firstly I am sharing the errors from Laravel via `boot()` in AppServiceProvider.php

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        Inertia::share([
            'errors' => function () {
                return Session::get('errors')
                    ? Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->getMessages()
                    : (object) [];
            },
        ]);

        Inertia::share('flash', function () {
            return [
                'message' => Session::get('message'),
            ];
        });
    }
```

Secondly I setup the Vue-File with the InertiaJS form helper. If I write instead of "`form.errors.asin" -> "$attrs.errors.asin`" the error will be displayed, but not within the form-Object and I don't know why is that.

**Index.vue**

```
<template>
  <main>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
        <div v-if="form.errors.asin">{{ form.errors.asin }}</div>
        <input id="asin" v-model="form.asin" label="ASIN:" />
        <button disabled="form.processing" type="submit"> Translate </button>
    </form>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

export default {
  setup() {
    const form = useForm({
      asin: null,
    });

    return { form };
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.form.get(
        "/translation/translate",
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**HandleInertiaRequests.php**

```
public function share(Request $request)
    {
        // In parent::share the error $attrs are shared
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'appName' => config('app.name'),
            'auth' => [
                'user' => $request->user()->only('id', 'email', 'is_admin', 'name'),
            ],
            'flash' => [
                'message' => function () use ($request) {
                    return [
                        'success' => $request->session()->get('success'),
                        'error' => $request->session()->get('error'),
                    ];
                }
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

As you see in the picture, the error is set under `$attrs.errors.asin` but not under form.errors

[Vue Debug Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrZv7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frontend part of inertia has different expectations regarding the errors.

You could:

a) grab the exact part you need from [here](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/blob/master/src/Middleware.php#L140) or

b) remove everything under `AppServiceProvider@boot` and create a new middleware extending Inertia's middleware - this will serve as a place to share all your additional props (the flash prop for example).

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Middleware;

class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    protected $rootView = 'app';

    public function version(Request $request)
    {
        return parent::version($request);
    }

    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            //
        ]);
    }
}
```

The middleware needs to be applied on the web group inside `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

Comment: I removed anything under `AppServiceProvider@boot` and had a look into my `HandleInertiaRequests.php` file. I attached the file in my main post. So there is already this function, which shares all errors via the `parent::share($request)` in the `Middleware.php` of Inertia.

The problem is not, that no error is displayed. The error is correctly shared and displayed as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrZv7.png but the problem is, that the error is shared as $attrs and not in the form Object of the `useForm-Helper` of Inertia.  Could you please have a second look? Thank you a lot!

Comment: And because of this behaviour I can't access any errors like this `<div v-if="form.errors.asin">` I have to check `<div v-if="$attrs.errors.asin">` which mainly isn't bad, but it's not working like the documentation of Inertia has written it here: https://inertiajs.com/forms#form-helper

Comment: Just made some tests on one of my projects. The only time the errors fail to show is when I'm using a get request. Can you change your request method to POST or PUT and see if that works?

Comment: Yessss! This is it. So with all other methods it's working, but not with GET. Many thanks for the testing. So the code is good, it seems to be a logical exception, that GET requests should not be used with forms with the Inertia form-Helper. If you do, you have to use `$attrs.errors` instead of `form.errors`.